# Rspec: Capybara select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I am using JS enabled Capybara with `selenium-webdriver` for my feature test.

I would like to select a brand from select box

**And here is my HTML**

```
<select id="campaign_brand_id" name="campaign[brand_id]" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Choose a Brand</option>
  <option value="1">Brand1</option>
  <option value="2">Brand2</option>
</select>
```

**Here is my test code**

```
before(:each) do
  @brand = FactoryGirl.create(:brand, name: 'Brand1', company: member.company)
end

scenario 'Create a new campaign - with minimum valid data', js: true do
  visit new_brands_campaign_url(host: "skreem.dev", port: Capybara.current_session.server.port)

  select (@brand.name), from: 'campaign_brand_id'
  click_button 'Create Campaign'
end
```

I have tried the following too...

```
1. select (@brand.name), from: 'campaign[brand_id]'
2. select (@brand.id), from: 'campaign_brand_id'
3. find('#campaign_brand_id').find(:xpath, "option[#{@brand.id}]").select_option
4. within '#campaign_brand_id' do
     find("option[value='1']").click
   end
```

Other capybara commands like `fill_in` `choose` `click_button` are working... I am using **`collection_select`** in the view... Is that causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about the not working?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get when doing `select @brand.name, from:"campaign_brand_id"` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost had it with xpath, but I try to avoid it due to how brittle it can be.

I use the following code, though recently I'm only running my tests with `capybara-webkit` rather than selenium:

```
option = @brand.name
find('#campaign_brand_id').find(
  'option', text: /#{option}/i).select_option
```

I use the text as a selector, as to me this is what the user sees and therefore is what a feature test should look for.
Also, I've used a regex to match the text to make it case insensitive - this is to prevent failing tests due to fickle UI changes such as up/down casing of words. It also saves you from the awkward problem of the css `text-transform` messing with the displayed vs. actual case of the text.

---

## Update

If the problem is still persisting, you will have to do some debugging. My suggestion is the [pry debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) gem. Add it to your gemfile and include the line `binding.pry` in the scenario above the line which is failing.
If I remember correctly, selenium runs only in the foreground, so you will be able to use the interactive pry console while seeing the page.

First try finding the select box (`find('#campaign_brand_id')`) and its options, then see what the selenium browser does while you are running the commands.

If you still don't have any luck, maybe these questions will help:

- Are there any errors or is it failing silently
- Is there any custom JS / CSS modifying your select boxes?
- Try interacting with the page via `execute_script` (see the [selenium driver docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Selenium/Driver) for details)

Comment: Still I am getting the same error... Other capybara commands like fill_in, choose, click_button are working fine... Can't understand the issue with select??? Added ScreenShot....

Answer (score -1):

use select without brackets:

```
select @brand.name, from: 'campaign[brand_id]'
```

or

```
select @brand.name, from: 'campaign_brand_id'
```

you can use id or name for option `from`

but if your form customized and real select is hidden, than you have to use another case